# how to groupby in dplyr with dataframe containing POSIXlt datatypes in r

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with date type as POSIXlt. When I groupby in dplyr it throws an error.

```
 delay_time <- vessel_data %>% 
   group_by(Service) %>% 
   dplyr::summarise(average_time <- mean(diff_pilot_alongside)) %>% 
   as.data.frame()
```

It throws following error

```
Error in grouped_df_impl(data, unname(vars), drop) : 
column 'arrival_pilot_station' has unsupported class : POSIXlt, POSIXt

arrival_pilot_station
"2016-03-21 16:18:00 IST"
"2016-04-01 03:12:00 IST"/
```

what is the work around to this problem ?

Comment: You need to use `POSIXct` instead of `POSIXlt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to convert the column to `POSIXct` as `dplyr` doesn't support `POSIXlt`

```
vessel_data %>% 
  mutate(arrival_pilot_station = as.POSIXct(arrival_pilot_station)) %>%
  group_by(Service) %>% 
  dplyr::summarise(average_time <- mean(diff_pilot_alongside)) %>% 
  as.data.frame()
```

Comment: how can I extract day of week and month from POSIXct ?

Comment: @Neil you can use `format(arrival_pilot_station, "%m")` for month and `format(arrival_pilot_station, "%w")` for week  or if you need the week name it should be `%a`

Comment: I have to bucket the time from 12am-6am,6am-12pm,12pm-6pm,6pm-12am. how can I do it? when  i extract the data its in the character type

Comment: @Neil  For that you may need to use `cut` after converting to `POSIXct`.